# Can't scrape empty <td> with python/selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to get values from a `<tr>` with Python Selenium, I need to have them ordered, and knowing which one has the value "PICK" and which doesn't.

To clarify, I need to know the position of the word "PICK" in the tr.
The problem is that my code isn't detecting the position, it always places on the second place, even if the word is located in the first position
( `pick=test.find_element_by_xpath('//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]').text` ).

The output is always this one:
`['', 'PICK']`.

Can you give me a hand with this? I need to have it ordered since I'm scraping a table and the results may vary depending on the PICK word, if its first td position or second...

Empty td code picture example:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to search '//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]' in browser DevTools > Elements ?

Comment: Okay, i solved the problem, is that I was accessing with // when I hard to access with .//

Comment: please provide the html, not a screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

I was accessing with `//` when I had to access with `.//`

---

<sub>This answer was posted as a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64525975/cant-scrape-empty-td-with-python-seleniumsolved#comment114131148_64525975) to the question [Can't scrape empty <td> with python/selenium[SOLVED]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64525975/cant-scrape-empty-td-with-python-seleniumsolved) by the OP [Adrian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14158865/adrian) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>